# How can I access a specific element within the Our World in Data COVID-19 Master Vaccinations JSON File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api-design

I'm relatively new to coding and am trying to access a specific element within COVID Vaccine JSON file created by Our World in Data, but I'm having a hard time with the syntax of my code/the structure of the JSON file.

I've successfully consumed the data from the JSON file (it's appearing in my inspector of the HTML page), but now I want to be able to call out a specific data field to display it in my HTML.

For example, I wanted the total number of people vaccinated in the United States on 04-07-2021 and was trying to the code below, but received `Cannot read property 'United States of undefined` as an error. Also, for context on my approach, I haven't learned how to use one of the frameworks yet, so I'm doing some DOM manipulation to get the data to display in the HTML.

```js
//110 is the total number of days that US vaccination data has been tracked, according to my math

var settings = {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(response);
    var content = response["country"]["United States"]["date"][110];
    document.getElementById("admin").innerHTML = response;
});
```

I also tried the following, which is also throwing errors:

```js
var settings = {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
};
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(response);
    var content = response.country[264].data.date[110]"
    document.getElementById("admin").innerHTML = response;
});
```

This is my first time writing code for a GET API call, so any and all feedback are welcome! For reference, the raw JSON file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.json) and their GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data/vaccinations) (file is named `vaccinations.json`). My HTML is also included below for additional context. Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vaccine Visualization</title>
    <!--enabled with jQuery-->
    <<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="vaccines.js"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:wght@400;600;800&family=Staatliches&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="vaccines-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="triangle">
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="header"> International COVID Vaccine Rollout </h1>
            <h2 class="subheader">PERCENT COMPLETE BY COUNTRY</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle2"></div>
    <div class="top-five-widget">
        <h2 class="top-five-title"> COVID Vaccine Distribution:<br>Top Five Countries</h2>
        <p>Total Vaccines Administered:</p>
        <span id="admin"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="vaccines.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Funniest error message I've seen today `"Cannot read property 'United States of undefined"`

Comment: @fortunee Username checks out :-(

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I looked at that post before I posted this and ended up just confusing myself - so seeing the brackets notation and curly braces broken out more distinctly was really helpful.

Comment: @fortunee That worked - you're a hero! And initially, I felt the same way about that error, but once I saw it for the 50th time, it quickly became less funny. Could you please explain why the syntax should be like that?

Comment: I didn't see any errors when I looked through inspector - did you see one @lux?

Comment: @WynPonder, I'm glad it worked. Could you give it an upvote and accepted the answer?

Comment: @fortunee Could you give some more detail into why that's the correct syntax? I just looked up the JS Array Find Method on W3Schools, but still not following completely. Thanks! Also, I accepted your answer and upvoted

Comment: @WynPonder, I made an EDIT to my suggestion with an explanation. Check it out. Also, thanks for accepting the answer, could you give it an upvote as well, clicking on the up arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should display the number of people vaccinated on '2021-04-07'

```js
var settings = {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  const USA = JSON.parse(response).find((data) => data.country === 'United States');
  const peopleVaccinated  = USA.data.find((d) => d.date === '2021-04-07').people_vaccinated;
  document.getElementById("admin").innerHTML = peopleVaccinated;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vaccine Visualization</title>
    <!--enabled with jQuery-->
    <<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="vaccines.js"></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:wght@400;600;800&family=Staatliches&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="vaccines-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style></style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="triangle">
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="header"> International COVID Vaccine Rollout </h1>
            <h2 class="subheader">PERCENT COMPLETE BY COUNTRY</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle2"></div>
    <div class="top-five-widget">
        <h2 class="top-five-title"> COVID Vaccine Distribution:<br>Top Five Countries</h2>
        <p>Total Vaccines Administered:</p>
        <span id="admin"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="vaccines.js"></script>

</body>
```

#### Explanation

The response is an `array` of `objects`, each `object` has a key of `country`.

So when I do a `.find`, it loops through the array looking for an object with a key of `country` equal to "United States" and saves it in a variable `USA`.

Which is what this line is doing.

```js
const USA = JSON.parse(response)
  .find((data) => data.country === 'United States');
```

`USA` itself is another `object` that has a key of `data` which is an `array` of `objects`.

So I do another `.find` on `USA.data` for the object with a key of `date` that is equal to '2021-04-07', and when it finds it we immediately chain `.people_vaccinated` to it.

That is this line:

```js
const peopleVaccinated  = USA.data
  .find((d) => d.date === '2021-04-07').people_vaccinated;
```

The rest should make sense to you.

Consider checking out [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) Like someone suggested in the comments.